# no puedo relacionar 2 tablas en xampp me tira como que ya estan relacionada

Tags: xampp

No puedo relacionar `id` con `año_id` me tira error la relación ya existe y es algo que hice pero no me sale como que este relacionado y no me deja ni eliminar campos ni ninguna otra cosa entonces no se que es lo que pasa en si cual puede ser el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en organizador yo veo la columna que servirá de llave foránea pero no veo el constraint por ningún lado

Comment: si ese campo que se llama año_id es el que quiero me funcione como llave foranea mmm el constrain como puedo realizarlo

Comment: bueno primer comentario, en la creación de los nombres de las columnas y las tablas no se usan caracteres como acentos, letra ñ y demás del tipo, por otro lado considero que lo mejor sería hacer esto a través de código

Comment: mmm bueno mas o menos como seria la consulta para intentar hacerla

Comment: coloca en tu pregunta en modo texto y separado por nombre de la tabla, el nombre de las columnas que deben componer a cada tabla

Comment: no pude realizarlo

Comment: que no pudiste? dime para ayudarte

Comment: como realizar la consulta me podrias mas o menos desarrolarla